# How do I permanently display user input from sibling component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-context

I have three test components that I have wrapped and I get the value from Test1 displayed on the DOM while the text is in the input field

The challenge is that the value 'disappears' as soon as the field clears.

I think I need to adjust the onChange method but I'm not sure how to go about getting the value from the user input in the Test1 component to be permanently available in the Tes2 component.

These are the test components.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Test1 from './components/Test1';
import Test2 from './components/Test2';

export const Context = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[userInput, setUserInput]}>
    <Test1/>
    <Test2/>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

The Test1, where the input field is

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../App";

export default function Test1() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!userInput) {
        alert("No value entered");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Form submitted!");
    console.log("You entered", userInput);
    setUserInput("");
    // e.target.reset();
  };

    const handleChange = event => {
      setUserInput(event.target.value);
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        <input
          id="user_input"
          name="user_input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="insert text here"
            onChange={handleChange}
          value={userInput}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button className="btn" type="submit" value={"Enter"}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

And the Test2 component, where I'm trying to read the input values from

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
// import Test1 from './Test1'
import {Context} from '../App';

export default function Test2() {
    const [userInput] = useContext(Context)

    return (
        <>
        <p>
            Getting {userInput} from Test1
        </p>
        </>
    )
}
```

I've tried lifting the state up and moving the single point of truth to the parent App component and passing the input value into another variable in Test2 and passing that variable to be displayed.

Comment: If you want to keep previously entered values you will need another state variable to hold them and logic as to when that separate state will be persisted, ie in your `handleSubmit`